# Cordova skip / stop updating plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I made some changes to a plugin and it work just like I want it. Now I want to keep those changes by not updating that plugin.

Is there a way to tell cordova to never update a plugin?

Is there another way to keep my changes when plugin source change?

Comment: when will cordova update your plugin automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why don't you remove plugin from package JSON whenever you need to update your other packages ?
2. Get a backup from your plugin so it doesn't change at all.
3. Fork and make a new repository and push your changes, so you can maintain your own custom plugin.